# How add custom button to ACF Wysiwyg tinymce?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

Im need add custom button to toolbar ACF Wysiwyg tinymce. I using this code:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'wdd_mce_format', function ( editor, url ) {
    editor.addButton( 'wdd_mce_format', {
        active: true,
        tooltip: 'Formating the List',
        text : 'Formating the List',
        icon : false,
        type : 'button',
        onclick : function () {
            do_stuff_here('')
        }
    } );
} );
```

Its good worked for standart Wordpress tinymce editor. But not work for ACF Wysiwyg tinymce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialization of ACF Wysiwyg toolbars ignory loading of tinymce plugins
This code solves the problem:

```
add_filter( 'acf/fields/wysiwyg/toolbars' , 'my_toolbars'  );
function my_toolbars( $toolbars )
{
    return array();
}
```

All plugins tinymce normally work